# What is the purpose of the 'graph' view in OpenERP 6?

Tags: forms, graph, tree, odoo

I have installed OpenERP & browsed through the code for each of the views. Whereas 'tree' & 'form' are self explanatory, I couldn't perceive what difference the 'graph' created. I have read these documentation sections:

1. [Graph views](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/graph_view.html)
2. The developer book's [table of contents](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/index.html#book-develop-link3).

I am looking for a 'why & what' rather than a 'how to' answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the Graph View is for taking managerial decisions like monthly Growth, monthly Sales etc. The Short Graph View is for comparing Sales, Purchase, Growth etc. in different periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

For me the 'graph' view is self explanatory too... For an object (example : product.product) you can have different type of views :

- Tree : to see a list of products,
- Form : to see the details of a product
- Graph : to have a graphical view of products like an histogram of the actual stock
- Gantt : ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I dug deeper into the code, re-read a couple of things and mapped it to the code. I got it!